# SlideMenuController left menu showing from start

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using SlideMenuControllerSwift but it's showing a portion of my left view from start, when I didn't even clicked the menu button. Any idea why this happens?

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
    let leftViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filterViewControllerID")
    let slide = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: vc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = slide
```

This is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking around I realised that the tableview containing the left view didn't have any constraint, the solution was just to add constraint's to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try these properties, maybe this could work:

```
public struct SlideMenuOptions {
    public static var leftViewWidth: CGFloat = ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH - 40
    public static var leftBezelWidth: CGFloat? = 16.0
    public static var contentViewScale: CGFloat = 1.0//0.96
    public static var contentViewOpacity: CGFloat = 0.5
    public static var shadowOpacity: CGFloat = 0.0
    public static var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0.0
    public static var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSizeMake(0,0)
    public static var panFromBezel: Bool = true
    public static var animationDuration: CGFloat = 0.4
    public static var rightViewWidth: CGFloat = 225.0
    public static var rightBezelWidth: CGFloat? = 16.0
    public static var rightPanFromBezel: Bool = true
    public static var hideStatusBar: Bool = true
    public static var pointOfNoReturnWidth: CGFloat = 44.0
    public static var simultaneousGestureRecognizers: Bool = true
    public static var opacityViewBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: It was closeLeft()

Comment: Try setting the above property

Comment: I make it to be the size of the screen but then I can't dismiss the menu, another think I don't know why it's happening is that is showing in the whole screen, and it always was 75% approx.

Comment: public static var contentViewScale: CGFloat = 0.96

Check this value, if its 0.96, then make it as 1.0

Comment: I had this value before

Comment: SlideMenuOptions.contentViewScale = 1
SlideMenuOptions.leftViewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

Comment: show me your slideMenuController class where you have set the properties

Comment: I use cocoapods, I set the SlideMenuOptions in the AppDelegate

Comment: Show me the properties you have set in your AppDelegate.

Comment: I pasted the two properties in a comment above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129621/discussion-between-ishika-and-aleixrr).